# Puppeteer on Linux Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, puppeteer, azure-linux

I am trying to run the Puppeteer on Linux Azure Web Apps. But log shows

> /node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-782078/chrome-linux/chrome:
> error while loading shared libraries: libgobject-2.0.so.0: cannot open
> shared object file: No such file or directory

I think it is due to the Linux distribution on Azure. And my question: Is it a dead end or is there something I can do about it?

Answer (score 9):

Looks like the default environments in App Service do not have the necessary dependencies for running headless Chromium. You can, however, run your app on App Service in a custom Docker image the dependencies installed. Here's a good starting point: https://github.com/buildkite/docker-puppeteer

Comment: I've come into this problem - And I'm running my puppeteer in a docker image using the buildkite/puppeteer base image. 

any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: If you are facing any problem to run puppeteer check out the [troubleshooting documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md). For this answer, consult [Running Puppeteer in Docker](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker).